# What query should I write for regex to capture the indicated paragraph formats and skip the rest?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex query to capture **either** forms of following paragraphs **from 'DIAGNOSIS' until before 'Board of pathologists'** and ignoring the rest. What is a good regex query for this?

("" indicate the beginning and the end of paragraphs and not included in the wanted string)

("THIS IS DIAGNOSIS..." and "diagnosis result" are sample texts for the sake of the question and are replaced by different things in the data)

**Paragraph format 1:**

"

DIAGNOSIS:

A- THIS IS THE DIAGNOSIS, NO.1:

- diagnosis results

B- THIS IS THE DIAGNOSIS, NO.2:

- diagnosis result
- another result

Board of pathologists:
. 
.
.

"

**Paragraph format 2:**

"

DIAGNOSIS:

THIS IS THE DIAGNOSIS:

- diagnosis results

Board of pathologists:
.
.
.

"

I used "DIAGNOSIS:(\s*)((\w*.\s*)*)". I know that this captures almost anything after diagnosis and my output shows that :) I couldn't find any better solution to capture the paragraphs.

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Can you not simply search for the string `THIS IS THE DIAGNOSIS`? You don’t even need a regex for that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have added my own query (that didn't work) and the output in the new edit

Comment: @mkrieger1 I need to capture the paragraphs that I indicated (from diagnosis till board) from a batch of documents and the documents have a lot of contents before and after these paragraphs. "THIS IS THE DIAGNOSIS" is a sample text. It will be replaced by other things in the data. Do you know a better way to do it?

Comment: @MRF Perhaps like this `^DIAGNOSIS:\s*(?:\r?\n)(?:(?!Board of pathologists:).*\r?\n)*` https://regex101.com/r/ZPIpA9/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match `^DIAGNOSIS:` form the start of the string.

Then you could repeatedly match the following lines that do not start with *Board of pathologists:* using a negative lookahead `(?:(?!Board of pathologists:).*\r?\n)*`

```
^DIAGNOSIS:\s*(?:\r?\n)(?:(?!Board of pathologists:).*\r?\n)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uiq3WG/1)